# Relace fragment and show loading dialog before the transaction ends

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am replacing a fragment with other that its a bit heavy and takes appreciable time to replace it. I am trying this but didn't show the loading dialog.

```
      final Handler handler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    currentFragment = currentFragment;
                    calendar = false;
                }
            };
 loadingDialog.show();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                //heavy job here
                //send message to main thread
                currentFragment = new StudentCalendarFragment();
                        if (currentFragment != null) {
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.tabs_fragment_container_fl, currentFragment);
                            fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
                            ft.commit();
                        }

                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                });
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss your dialog not after `commit()` but in `StudentCalendarFragment.onResume()` method. Commit just schedules a commit of your transaction. The fragment is active only after its `onResume()` method was called.

Comment: same result as before

Comment: @Jachumbelechao Unto Mantekilla Try to create and show loadingDialog in loadingDialog.onAttach() and dismiss it in onResume. Is the problem in that dialog is disappearing too fast or it's even not shown?

Comment: show it in the onAttach() of the fragment? like this it shows but after fragment is loaded